# TrigExpand-ing too far

Tags: fourier-analysis, trigonometry

Something simple: I'd like `TrigExpand[Sin[3n-3]]` to return `Sin[3n]Cos[3]-Cos[3n]Sin[3]` instead of `-Cos[n]^3 Sin[3]+3 Cos[3] Cos[n]^2 Sin[n]+3 Cos[n] Sin[3] Sin[n]^2-Cos[3] Sin[n]^3`.

Is there a way to get Mathematica to expand the addition/sum without expanding the multiplier(s)?

(The reason: I'm working with Fourier series and I want to be able to see things as combinations of `Sin[a n]` and `Cos[a n]`.)

Comment: `expLmtd[exp_, var_] := Module[{k},
  TrigExpand[exp /. Times[s_, var] :> k[s, var]] /. 
   k :> Times]; expLmtd[Sin[3 n - 3], n]`

Comment: @belisariusisforth why not answer it with that? Looks like a nice approach to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
expLmtd[exp_, var_] := Block[{k = Unique[]}, 
                       TrigExpand[exp /. Times[s_, var] :> k[s, var]] /.  k :> Times]
expLmtd[Sin[3 n - 3], n]

(* -Cos[3 n] Sin[3] + Cos[3] Sin[3 n] *)
```