# Simplifying a function to get rid of fractional powers of $-1$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, simplifying-expressions, complex

I have the following function for $x>0$.

```
expression=14 (-1)^(1/7)Cos[x] (105 - 99 (-1)^(1/7) + 103 (-1)^(2/7) - 103 (-1)^(3/7) +  99 (-1)^(4/7) - 105 (-1)^(5/7) + 155 (-1)^(6/7) +  64 (-1)^(6/7) Cos[4 x] +  8 Cos[2 x] (17 - 16 (-1)^(1/7) - 17 (-1)^(3/7) + 16 (-1)^(4/7) + 24 (-1)^(6/7) + 34 Sin[(3 π)/14]))
```

and I expect (hope!) that it can be expressed in the following simple form where $a,b,c$ are some **real** numbers

```
a Cos[x] + b Cos[3 x] +  c Cos[5 x]
```

I use `FullSimplify` but cannot get rid of those fractional powers of $-1$ which results in imaginary values. Can someone please help me with this problem? I appreciate any comments.

Comment: Hi, the 14 (-1)^(1/7) at the beginning is supposed to multiply the expression ? On my notebook it is considered to be on a different line. Other than that you can use `expression  // ComplexExpand // TrigReduce`

Comment: I edited the text, and yes, it is a multiplicative factor.

Comment: does `expression  // ComplexExpand // TrigReduce` work for your case ?

Comment: Yes, it worked and it gave the desired result. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, sorry my comment above did not answer your question. See my answer below for a possible solution.

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer I gave. That answer might have its benefit when the `FullSimplify` solutions provided in other answers are slow or do not work but generically  their answers are easier to use and so should be accepted instead. In particular Bob Hanlon's method of using `FullSimplify` directly is rather convenient to use and in my opinion should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach:

```
a = FourierCosCoefficient[expression,x,1] // FullSimplify
b = FourierCosCoefficient[expression,x,3] // FullSimplify
c = FourierCosCoefficient[expression,x,5] // FullSimplify
```

This returns the first two coefficients as roots objects. But I think the main advantage is to have isolated the three coefficients, in case one wants to do further computations with them.

It is a good idea to check that we really have the right expression:

```
expression - (a*Cos[x] + b*Cos[3*x] + c*Cos[5*x]) // FullSimplify
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: Nice, I did not know about that. For the expansion apparently one can also use `FourierTrigSeries[expression, x, 5]` which has the benefit of including both `Cos` and `Sin` terms (for expression where they could exist).

Comment: Using Bob Hanlon's method it seems the Root  objects can be turned into trigonometric expressions using `// ToRadicals // ComplexExpand`

Answer (score 3):

```
expression= 14 (-1)^(1/7)Cos[x] (105 - 99 (-1)^(1/7) + 103 (-1)^(2/7) - 103 (-1)^(3/7) +  99 (-1)^(4/7) - 105 (-1)^(5/7) + 155 (-1)^(6/7) +  64 (-1)^(6/7) Cos[4 x] +  8 Cos[2 x] (17 - 16 (-1)^(1/7) - 17 (-1)^(3/7) + 16 (-1)^(4/7) + 24 (-1)^(6/7) + 34 Sin[(3 \[Pi])/14]))
```

A first approach could be `expression //ComplexExpand //TrigReduce` but that includes phases in the `Cos` and `Sin` which you might not want. If we then use `TrigExpand`, the  result will be "trig-expanded" too much as it will also "trig-expand" terms like `Cos[3*x]`. A solution for that is given in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96935/86543) (I made a slight modification by setting up the function in the form of a sub-value for convenience):

```
expLmtd[var_][exp_] := 
Block[{k = Unique[]}, 
      TrigExpand[exp /. Times[s_, var] :> k[s, var]] 
                     /.  k :> Times]
```

If we include [`Collect`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect.html) to simplify the expression one can do:

```
Collect[expression // ComplexExpand // TrigReduce // expLmtd[x], 
Cos[x*Range[5]], Simplify]
```

Out:  $ -448 \cos (5 x)+14 \cos (x) \left(-251+342 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{14}\right)-326 \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{14}\right)+346 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{7}\right)\right)+112 \cos (3 x) \left(17 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{14}\right)-16 \left(1+\sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{14}\right)\right)+17 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{7}\right)\right) $

Comment: Does someone know why the answer in the link given used Block[{k=Unique[]}, ... ] instead of Module[{k},...] ?

Comment: In the same thread, Dr. belisarius has a comment where they use `Module`, so perhaps the reason is subtle. I'd be concerned that all these `Unique[]` will be lurking around afterwards. One could also use `Module[{k}, expLmtd[var_][exp_]:=...]` with `Module` on the outside, since there is no reason to create a new symbol for each invocation.

Comment: @user293787 I looked at `MemoryInUse[]`, `Names["k*"]` and `Names["$*"]` and I did see that the `Block` method uses memory but I did not notice a difference between defining the function `expLmtd` outside or inside the `Module`. The local variables in `Module` have attribute Temporary so they should be removed in this case as they are not explicitly used in the output.

Comment: I agree, only the version with Unique[] will leak memory. The point of moving Module out of the definition would just be to remove any overhead associated to Module (I do not know if [this old answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8228/85954) is still valid).

Answer (score 2):

```
expression = 
 14 (-1)^(1/7) Cos[
   x] (105 - 99 (-1)^(1/7) + 103 (-1)^(2/7) - 103 (-1)^(3/7) + 
    99 (-1)^(4/7) - 105 (-1)^(5/7) + 155 (-1)^(6/7) + 
    64 (-1)^(6/7) Cos[4 x] + 
    8 Cos[2 x] (17 - 16 (-1)^(1/7) - 17 (-1)^(3/7) + 16 (-1)^(4/7) + 
       24 (-1)^(6/7) + 34 Sin[(3 \[Pi])/14]))

test = a Cos[x] + b Cos[3 x] + c Cos[5 x]

res = expression // ExpToTrig // TrigReduce // FullSimplify // Distribute

{Cos[# x], Last@CoefficientList[res, Cos[# x]]} & /@ {1, 3, 5} // 
 Grid[#, Spacings -> {4, 1}, Alignment -> {Left, Center}, 
   ItemSize -> {Automatic, 1}] &
```

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 \cos (x) & 14 \left(-251+342 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{14}\right)-326 \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{14}\right)+346 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{7}\right)\right) \\
 \cos (3 x) & 112 \left(17 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{14}\right)-16 \left(1+\sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{14}\right)\right)+17 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{7}\right)\right) \\
 \cos (5 x) & -448 \\
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

expression = 
  14 (-1)^(1/7) Cos[
    x] (105 - 99 (-1)^(1/7) + 103 (-1)^(2/7) - 103 (-1)^(3/7) + 
     99 (-1)^(4/7) - 105 (-1)^(5/7) + 155 (-1)^(6/7) + 
     64 (-1)^(6/7) Cos[4 x] + 
     8 Cos[2 x] (17 - 16 (-1)^(1/7) - 17 (-1)^(3/7) + 16 (-1)^(4/7) + 
        24 (-1)^(6/7) + 34 Sin[(3 π)/14]));

expression2 = expression // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify

(* 14 (-32 Cos[5 x] + 
   Cos[x] (-251 + 346 Cos[π/7] + 342 Sin[π/14] - 
      326 Sin[(3 π)/14]) + 
   8 Cos[3 x] (17 Cos[π/7] + 17 Sin[π/14] - 
      16 (1 + Sin[(3 π)/14]))) *)

expression3 = 
 expression2 // RootReduce // ToRadicals // ComplexExpand // 
  FullSimplify

(* 28/3 (-48 Cos[5 x] + 
   Cos[x] (-123 + 14 Sqrt[3] Cos[1/3 ArcCot[(39 Sqrt[3])/71]]) + 
   4 Cos[3 x] (-23 + Sqrt[7] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[3 Sqrt[3]]])) *)
```

The expressions are equal for real `x`

```
expression == expression2 == expression3 //
 FullSimplify[#, Element[x, Reals]] &

(* True *)

LeafCount /@ {expression, expression2, expression3}

(* {108, 71, 65} *)
```